# Performance consequences of declaring variables with "var" (Local-Variable Type Inference)

Tags: java

There is any performance consequence when declaring variables with "var"?

What about the difference in the generated bytecode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `var` keyword doesn't have any performance consequences as the type for the local variable will be resolved by the compiler at the compile time.

`java` is always a static typed language.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse Java's `var` keyword with Javascript's. Java is statically typed so all local variable type resolution will be done at compile time. It should not have any effect on the generated bytecode or runtime performance.

Comment: "should" or "must" / "will not" / "does not"?